# how to test cross platform funtioanlity of a QT Application

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I have build a QT simple stock management application i want to test the cross platform funtionality i just wanted to know whats the best way to do this .

How can i achieve it.i researched it through but no solid information was available .

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Squish can be used for gui testing. It's quite useful for testing qt widget functionality as well.  https://www.froglogic.com/squish/

Comment: If you mean "does it build on other platforms", for Windows and MacOS you'll need to acquire a copy of the OS to run somewhere (VM or real hardware); Linux and the BSDs can run a live ISO in a VM and you can test the build there (although getting the dependencies installed might be a struggle).

Comment: If you mean "does it run in X, framebuffer and Wayland platforms", then you can use environment variables to switch, like `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` (on Linux or the BSDs)